# USB dock for 4TB Seagate HDD only works with less then 2.2TB of data

Tags: 14.04, usb, external-hdd, gpt

I have one of those Seagate 4TB HD and everything went fine using GPT, I could use it normally without any problem. I used gparted to format and create the partition table as ext4.

Everything changed as soon as I reach 2.2TB of data on the disk. After this point, I no longer could use it on my USB dock and everytime I try to use it, dmesg shows it as a 2.2TB drive:

```
[787067.503166] sd 28:0:0:0: [sdc] 4294967295 512-byte logical blocks: (2.19 TB/1.99 TiB)
```

But, if I plug it right onto my internal SATA port it works nicely.

The same happens if I try to use the e-sata port from the USB dock.

Comment: I'm curious as to what dmesg says when it's plugged in to your internal SATA port.

Comment: [    1.623603] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.63 TiB)

Comment: Which USB dock? USB id's, Make/Model, chipset if known.

Comment: What does `lsusb` say about the USB<->SATA connector?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Both `152d:2352 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. ATA/ATAPI Bridge` and `048d:1336 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. SD/MMC Cardreader` appears only when I plug in the USB

Comment: @marked  it is a [generic dock station](http://www.fonecar.com.br/Eshop.Admin/imagens/fonecar/Thumbs/TN500_DOCKING%203.jpg) model 876C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.2 TB ≈ 2 TiB, which corresponds to the largest number of 512-byte blocks addressable by 32 bits (2<sup>32</sup> × 512 B = 2<sup>32</sup> × 2<sup>9</sup> B = 2<sup>41</sup> = 2 × 1024<sup>4</sup> B = 2 TiB). I suspect that your USB-to-ATA bridge doesn't support more blocks or larger blocks, because it's cheap and/or old.

Does your storage drive allow you to set the block size to 4 KiB ([Advanced Format](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format))? Many newer drives allow the selection of a legacy mode with 512 B through a set of jumpers (see example picture below), which is often the default. If so, it's worth a try, but in that case you'll need to repartition the drive. Simply changing the jumper, trying to read the drive and changing it back, won't harm any existing data though, as long as you don't write anything while the jumper is out of its original position.

[image: Example for disk drive jumpers]

Comment: I guess the fact it is just a cheap device, the problem lies there. Unfortunately I cannot reformat the hard drive to test this solution. Yet, I accept this as the right answer.

Comment: The jumper [just adds](https://bit-tech.net/reviews/tech/storage/the-facts-4k-advanced-format-hard-disks/2/) an internal "+1 shift" to the sector number to access for every OS request. It's just there to help with [sector alignment](https://superuser.com/questions/291978/western-digital-green-drive-from-512-byte-sectors-jumpered-to-4k-byte-sectors) in older systems and doesn't influence in any shape or form the physical sector size.

Comment: @mirh: It seems that this specific jumper on the depicted drive is indeed unrelated to advanced format drives (4K sector size). That’s an unfortunate coincidence and I’m going to edit my answer to use a different image to illustrate hard drive jumpers.

Comment: I mean, that's [instead](https://www.pcstats.com/articles/1778/4.html) an old jumper to adjust between the master and slave role. I guess some IDE docks will [require](https://mypages.iit.edu/~kbloom1/blog/Using_a_JMicron_JM20337_USB_IDE_adapter_with_linux.html) tinkering with that, but this is quite not it. I don't think one to change sector size ever existed anywhere (there are [tools](https://superuser.com/a/1508559/567466) to do that though). JMB352 is probably suffering of the same kind of bug of [JM20337](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306857/536967).

Comment: @mirh In that case my hard drive either doesn’t exist or its documentation is faulty. According to its label there is a jumper to switch between 512 and 4096 byte sector size.

Comment: Mhh, really? What model is it?